# 1D transient heat equation problem with controller

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

I would appreciate some help with following issue:

I am trying to solve a 1D transient heat equation problem with a control loop in order to compensate a time variable boundary condition at one extremity, so that the temperature at the other extremity stays stable around 25.

$u(t,x)$ obeys to following PDE on a x-line from 0 to 10:

$u^{(0,1)}(x,t)=u^{(2,0)}(x,t)+ \operatorname{compensator}(t)$,

with:

Initial condition: $u(0,x)=25$
Boundary conditions: $u(t,0)=25+ 3 \sin \left(\frac{t}{50}\right)$ and $u^{(0,1)}(t,10)=0$

the compensator is the output from a P-controller: $\operatorname{compensator}(t)=-0.05(u(t, 10) - 25)$
If that works, I would then like to try with a PI or PID-controller.

Here is the code I have tried in *Mathematica* 11 (just replace 0 by 1 before 0.05 to activate the controller and get the error):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 0.5*D[u[t, x], x, x] - 0*0.05*(u[t, 10] - 25),
u[0, x] == 25,
u[t, 0] == 25 + 3*Sin[t/50],
(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 10) == 0},
u,{t, 0, 1000}, {x, 0, 10}]

{Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 1000}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {"Time", "x"}, PlotLegends -> {"usol(t,x)"}, PlotTheme ->"Detailed",ImageSize -> 300],

Plot[Evaluate[sol[t, x] /. x -> {0, 10}, {t, 0, 1000}],ImageSize -> 300,   PlotLegends -> Table[Style[StringJoin["x=", ToString[i]], 
  FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Cambria Math"], {i, {0, 10}}], 
PlotStyle -> Table[RGBColor[0.1, j, 0.5], {j, 0, 1, 1/2}], PlotTheme ->"Detailed", 
PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {Style["Time", 12, FontFamily -> "Cambria Math"]}]}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/partial-differential-equations/solve-pdes-with-events-over-regions.html?product=mathematica) is useful.

Comment: Delay partial differential equations are not supported

Comment: @DavidBaghdasaryan, what makes this a delay PDE? I fail to see that.

Comment: You can solve this problem by discretizing space and using the method of lines. I don't have time now to write this explicitly, but perhaps you can get the idea from [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) (note that in the example there they discretize time and not space and you need to do the opposite).

Comment: @user21: thanks for the link, I already had a look on this way of using WhenEvent to model a thermostat. This could probably work here as well, but this would only be for an on-off controller. I would prefer a solution where I can at some point implement a PI and PID-controller as well.

Comment: @ David Baghdasaryan & user21: curiously the first error message is indeed "Delay partial diff. eq. are not currently supported by NDSolve". Any idea why? I can't see neither some kind of delay-pde here.

Comment: `NDSolve` is just moody today....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
f[tt_?NumericQ, u_] := If[tt <= 0., 25, u /. {t -> tt, x -> 10}]
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
    0.5*D[u[t, x], x, x] - 0.05*(f[t, u[t, x]] - 25), u[0, x] == 25, 
   u[t, 0] == 25 + 3*Sin[t/50], (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 10) == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, 1000}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Which gives me these plots:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the amazing f(t,u(t,x))-trick, this kind of thing always looks to me like pulling a rabbit out of a hat. I'll try with PI and PID-controller now.